# product_attribute_media.list gives Product not exists error in Magento

Tags: php, magento, soap

According to magento, this is the parameter list for the SOAP (v1) **product_attribute_media.list** call:

[image]
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/catalog_product_attribute_media.list.html

I have a numeric sku (e.g. 123456). So, when I call this api method, I get **Product not exists.** soap fault.

This is my code:

```
// Load existing images
$existingImages = $proxy->call(
    $sessionId,
    'catalog_product_attribute_media.list',
    (string)$SKU,
    $storeId,
    'sku'
);
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

---

Before you ask; yes this product in **$SKU** (e.g. 123456) does exists in magento at the specified store id, I have already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this: http://allabouttodd.com/story/magento-api-media-call-returns-product-not-exists-error-valid-sku

I have fixed it like this:

```
// Load existing images
$existingImages = $proxy->call(
    $sessionId,
    'catalog_product_attribute_media.list',
    (string)$SKU .' ',
    $storeId,
    'sku'
);
```